# Can an Office 2007 Custom Ribbon with a menu be done without the image column?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vsto, office-interop

I am currently making a custom Ribbon for office 2007.  I am using the menu control.  When the menu is shown it has a left hand small column (for an image) and large right column.  Is there any way to only have one column and thus have no images?

Or is there another control that I can put in the menu that goes all the way across as if it was only one column?

[image]

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by image column? Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Please see picture. Those little flags are images and as you can see a column is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I have got for anyone coming here is that you cannot do it.